# React Autocomplete widget select item on key navigation from the drop down menu

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, menu, key, selection

I am using React Autocomplete

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-autocomplete
```

which working fine as shown below

```
 <Autocomplete
                    value={this.state.value}
                    inputProps={inputProps}
                    wrapperStyle={{ position: 'absolute', display: 'inline-block' }}
                    items={this.state.srnList}
                    getItemValue={item => item.name}
                    shouldItemRender={matchSRN}
                    onChange={(event, value) =>
                        this.setState({ value, loading: false })
                    }
                    onSelect={this.onSelectFunc}
                    renderMenu={(items, value) => (
                        <div className="menu">
                            {items.length < 1 ? (
                                <div className="item">loading ...</div>
                            ) : items}
                        </div>
                    )}

                    renderItem={(item, isHighlighted) => (
                        <div
                            className={`item ${isHighlighted ? 'item-highlighted' : ''}`}
                            key={item.code} >
                            <a href={'/InstallBase/sitePage/' + item.name.split(',')[0]}>{item.name}</a>
                        </div>
                    )}
                />
```

In the above implementation the section of items happens on click of the menu items

Wanted to know how to select the item on key navigation or on enter select the first match item in the list display below of the menu

Answer (score 0):

Removed the renderMenu function working as expected